# Make the whole match non-capturing in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex like the following:

```js
const regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;

const result = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(regex);

console.log(result)
```

Here, the result is having the first item as a whole match, is it possible to exclude the whole match from the result in anyway? Currently I ended up doing a `shift()` on the result, just wondering if the whole match can me marked as non-capturing in anyway.

Comment: No, but you may use destructuring if you want. Like `const [_, year,month,day,hour,minute,second] = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(regex);`

Comment: There is no regex method in JS that would not return the whole match.

Comment: I think that answers my question, the destructing looks clean and very much readable. Thank you.

Comment: If you know the input format is OK, then you can do `result = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(/\d+/g)`. Or with a bit more checking: `.match(/^(\d{4}|\b\d{2})\b/g)`

Comment: @trincot Thank you for the cherry on top :) I am not that proficient in regex trying to learn regex these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use destructuring to split-off the first value from the result array with `[,...result]`:

```js
const regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;

const [,...result] = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(regex);

console.log(result)
```

If you know the input format is OK, then you can do:

```
result = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(/\d+/g)
```

```js
const regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;

const result = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(/\d+/g);

console.log(result)
```

Or with a bit more checking: `.match(/(^\d{4}|\b\d{2})\b/g)`

```js
const regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;

const result = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(/(^\d{4}|\b\d{2})\b/g);

console.log(result)
```

Additionally, if you want to have the array with the numeric data type equivalents, then map using `Number` as callback function:

```js
const regex = /(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;

const [,...result] = ("1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(regex)||[]).map(Number);

console.log(result)
```

The additional `||[]` treats the case where the pattern does not match, and exchanges the `null` with an empty array.

Comment: I am getting a feeling that I should read some article showing the different possibilities of destructing.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [named groups](http://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-named-capture-groups.html)

```js
const regex = /((?<year>\d{4})-(?<month>\d{2})-(?<day>\d{2})) (?<hour>\d{2}):(?<minutes>\d{2}):(?<seconds>\d{2})/;

const result = "1988-02-01 12:12:12".match(regex).groups;

console.log(result)

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: This is really interesting, nice new feature.

Comment: The only downside I can think of is that iteration order is not guaranteed for Object which applies for `Object.values` AFAIK. But the Object by itself is useful.

Comment: Take care that doesn't work with all browsers, for example Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with trincot and use deconstructoring. According to the Mozilla docs, having the full match go into the 1st index is by design:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec :

Object: result

Property/Index: [0]

Description: **The full string of characters matched**